# How to convert from Base36 to Base10 in JS

Tags: javascript, radix

I have a base36 number 00001CGUMZYCB99J

But if I try convert it in JavaScript to base 10 with

```
parseInt("00001CGUMZYCB99J", 36);
```

I get wrong results like 177207000002463650 or 177207000002463648. The expected result is 177207000002463655. I found two websites that get the result right anyway: [translatorscafe](http://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/en/numbers/) and [dcode](http://www.dcode.fr/base-n-convert).

But how can I do this in JS?

Comment: This is an accuracy problem, but I don't know how to solve one in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outcome of that conversion exceeds [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (i.e. the base-10 value is too large to fit in a JavaScript integer), which means you need some sort of arbitrary precision library to do the conversion, for instance [`biginteger`](https://github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger):

```
const BigInteger = require('biginteger').BigInteger;

let value = BigInteger.parse('00001CGUMZYCB99J', 36);

console.log( value.toString() ) // 177207000002463655
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript stores all values in a `double`. Therefore, large numbers will have some of the less significant digits changed. If you want to deal with large numbers, you have to use a special library like [this BigInteger one](https://github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger).

If you use this library, you can convert between bases like this:

```
BigInteger.parse("00001CGUMZYCB99J", 36);
```

Keep in mind that you need to keep using the library, you can't convert it back into a normal number, or you will face the same problem.